# How are the results from glob ordered?

Tags: c, linux, glob

I am reading files in a directory using :

```
glob_t* globlist;
// initialization.
glob(pattern, GLOB_ERR | GLOB_BRACE, NULL, globlist);
```

This works well, but now the order of processing for each file is relevant, so I would like to know if there is a specific ordering for the matches, or if there is none, if it is possible to specify in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quoted from the man page [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html)

> The pathnames shall be in sort order as defined by the current setting of the LC_COLLATE category;

Answer (score 1):

By default `glob` sort the returned names.

From [the POSIX reference page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html):

> GLOB_NOSORT
>
> Ordinarily, glob() sorts the matching pathnames according to the current setting of the LC_COLLATE category; see XBD LC_COLLATE. When this flag is used, the order of pathnames returned is unspecified.